# Picturebox1.load sudden failure

Tags: download, picturebox

Suddenly when I use Picturebox1.load to download an image from the Internet I get this error:

The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I have used this for years and never had any problems.
What's interesting is, if I create a WebBrowser control, I can navigate directly to the picture and save it that way. But this is a long roundabout method of a basic function.
Why would Picturebox1.Load suddenly stop working?

Here is the URL of the image I am trying to save:
https://img.gsmls.com/imagedb/highres/75/101537932_1.jpg

Comment: I am thinking maybe I need to add a Web header... Does this make sense? Can you add a header to the Picturebox control? Any other ways around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I just removed the s from the URL, so now it's http:// instead of https://, and its back to working normally. Not sure if this is a real fix.